# what is the tightness of $D^\kappa$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $D$ be $\{0,1\}$. My question is this:

> For any $\kappa$, what is the tightness of $D^\kappa$?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$A compact space is called a *dyadic space* if it is a continuous image of $D^\kappa$ for some $\kappa\ge\omega$. If $X$ is dyadic, $t(X)=w(X)$, so $t(D^\kappa)=\kappa$. (This is a non-trivial result; it’s Problem 3.12.12(h) in Engelking’s 1977 *General Topology*.)

**Added:** The result just for $D^\kappa$ isn’t too hard. For $\eta\le\kappa$ define $p_\eta\in D^\kappa$ by

$$p_\eta(\xi)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if }\xi<\eta\\0,&\text{otherwise}\;,\end{cases}$$

and let $A=\{p_\eta:\eta\le\kappa\}$. Note that $A$ is closed in $D^\kappa$, since if $x\in D^\kappa\setminus A$, there are $\xi<\eta<\kappa$ such that $x(\xi)=0$ and $x(\eta)=1$.

It’s not hard to check that the map $h:\kappa+1\to A:\xi\mapsto p_\xi$ is a homeomorphism. It follows immediately that if $\kappa$ is regular, then $p_\kappa$ is not in the closure of any $S\subseteq A$ with $|S|<\kappa$ and hence that $t(D^\kappa)\ge\kappa$. If $\kappa$ is singular, let $\lambda$ be any regular infinite cardinal less than $\kappa$. Then $\{p_\xi:\xi\le\lambda\}$ is a closed copy of the linearly ordered space $\lambda+1$, which has tightness $\lambda$. Thus,

$$t(D^\kappa)\ge\sup\{\lambda<\kappa:\lambda\text{ is regular}\}=\kappa$$

in this case as well. On the other hand, $t(D^\kappa)\le w(D^\kappa)=\kappa$, so $t(D^\kappa)=\kappa$.

Comment: Also Problem 3.12.12(h) in the 1989 "revised and completed edition" of Engelking's _General Topology_.